# PHP+HTML - If Else, Hide Button

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

This is my php code:

```
if ($value = $rec['ip'] <= $cphigh_ip && $cplow_ip <= $value = $rec['ip'])
{
    $cpyes="on ";
    $realString = $value = $rec['ip'];
    $whmLink=$realString[strlen($realString)-1];
}
else
{
    $cpno="not on cPanel";
}
```

And the HTML table I have is pretty simple:

```
<tr>
    <td>Domain IP:</td>
    <td><?=$ipyes.$ipno.$cpyes.$cpno;?><input type="submit" name="cPanelButton" onClick="window.location.href='https://cp<?=$whmLink; ?>.skycomp.ca:2087'" value="cPanel"></td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to hide the button in the else clause? or even create the button in that specific  in the if statement?

Comment: set a variable to true / false in your if/else and then use it to add the class in your html.

Comment: @Unex what would that look like in the HTML? like `<? if ($button=true) <input="submit" . . . > ?>` ?

Comment: you got the idea. That would be great if you could find the answer by yourself with this tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put button in to php code

```
if ($value = $rec['ip'] <= $cphigh_ip && $cplow_ip <= $value = $rec['ip'])
    {
        $cpyes="on ";
        $realString = $value = $rec['ip'];
        $whmLink=$realString[strlen($realString)-1];
        $ifwhmlink = '<input type="submit" name="cPanelButton"   onClick="window.location.href=\'https://cp'.$whmLink.'.skycomp.ca:2087\'" value="cPanel">';
    }
    else
    {
        $cpno="not on cPanel";
        $ifwhmlink = "";
    }
```

---

```
<tr>
    <td>Domain IP:</td>
    <td><?=$ipyes.$ipno.$cpyes.$cpno.$ifwhmlink;?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

One of a few different ways is to set a flag:

```
$show_button = TRUE;
if ($value = $rec['ip'] <= $cphigh_ip && $cplow_ip <= $value = $rec['ip'])
{
    $cpyes="on ";
    $realString = $value = $rec['ip'];
    $whmLink=$realString[strlen($realString)-1];
} else {
    $show_button = FALSE;
    $cpno="not on cPanel";
}
```

Then, in your HTML, wrap it in an `if` condition:

```
<?php if ($show_button) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Domain IP:</td>
        <td><?=$ipyes.$ipno.$cpyes.$cpno;?><input type="submit" name="cPanelButton" onClick="window.location.href='https://cp<?=$whmLink; ?>.skycomp.ca:2087'" value="cPanel"></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Which will hide the whole ROW.  If you want to just hide the button, then:

```
<tr>
    <td>Domain IP:</td>
    <td><?php if ($show_button) { ?><?=$ipyes.$ipno.$cpyes.$cpno;?><input type="submit" name="cPanelButton" onClick="window.location.href='https://cp<?=$whmLink; ?>.skycomp.ca:2087'" value="cPanel"><?php } ?></td>
</tr>
```